# How can I use EntityFrameWorkStores to manage user accounts and also access Microsoft Graph?

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, identity

We have an application that uses Microsoft Identity (not webapp Identity) for Authentication. We manage Authorization using a local DB, with DefaultItentity, EntityFrameWorkStores, etc..., as shown in the first part of the code example below (right below the DB connection).

Now, we want to access Microsoft Graph. We've tried this using the second part of the code example (just below the EntityFrameWorkStores line). I believe this is for authentication with regard to Microsoft Graph. But, as you can see, it adds MicrosoftIdentityWebApp. And if I take out that line, the AddMicrosoftGraph does not work.

What I don't understand is how to properly use both of these. How to manage user Authorization with my local Identity stores in my DB, AND be able to use Microsoft Graph. Obviously Microsoft Graph needs to authenticate, but how do I Authenticate with Identity and Microsoft Graph at the same time? Or, how can I use the Microsoft Identity Authentication to provide access to Microsoft Graph?

I've seen a number of examples online where the second part is used, but not the first part. And I have not found an example that uses both.

One last thing. I have to use delegated permissions, with regard to the app registration. I cannot use Application Permissions, as that would give me more access than what is needed.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<InvoiceAuditingContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    
// Identity
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
    .AddUserStore<UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, InvoiceAuditingContext, Guid>>()
    .AddRoleStore<RoleStore<ApplicationRole, InvoiceAuditingContext, Guid>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<InvoiceAuditingContext>();

// Authentication for Microsoft Graph?
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

I don't mean to sound ungrateful, but please do not send me links on how to implement Microsoft Graph. I know how to use Microsoft Graph, and I also know how to only implement Microsoft Graph.

Answer (score 0):

You need an Azure Active Directory (AAD) account and application with permissions to access Microsoft Graph API and SPO site. Then you can call Microsoft Graph API to access the site list using an app token.

Here is the overview of Working with SharePoint sites in Microsoft Graph:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Don't mean to be rude, but did you actually read the content or just the question headline? I've seen this article long ago. We are already working with MS Graph and getting files from SharePoint.  My question is about managing Identity accounts in a local store, and if I can link an Identity account with MS Graph. The article you shared does no show how to do that. So, could you please clarify your answer?

Comment: I cannot use Application permissions. I have to use Delegated permissions.